# In React, how can I calculate the width of a parent based on it's child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a draggable carousel slider in React and I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the total width of the containing div based on the number of child elements it contains. I assumed I would be able to get the width after the component mounted but it didn't return the result I was expecting...I now assume it needs to wait for the images to be loaded and mounted to do this. What would be the best way to get the width of the `<div className="carousel__stage">`?

```
const Carousel = () => {
  const carouselStage = useRef(null);

  useEffect ( () => {
    console.log(carouselStage.scrollWidth);
  }, [carouselStage]);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <div ref={carouselStage} className="carousel__stage">
        <Picture />
        <Picture />
        <Picture />
        <Picture />
        <Picture />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you assign specific width to the parent element of an image that also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for [`ResizeObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

```
function useResizeObserver() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const resizeObserver = useRef(null);

  const onResize = useCallback((entries) => {
    const { width, height } = entries[0].contentRect;
    setSize({ width, height });
  }, []);

  const ref = useCallback(
    (node) => {
      if (node !== null) {
        if (resizeObserver.current) {
          resizeObserver.current.disconnect();
        }
        resizeObserver.current = new ResizeObserver(onResize);
        resizeObserver.current.observe(node);
      }
    },
    [onResize]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      resizeObserver.current.disconnect();
    },
    []
  );

  return { ref, width: size.width, height: size.height };
}
```

[image: Edit ResizeObserver Example]

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback function to each Pictures and use useState hook to calculate total width.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(200); //default width
const handleImageLoaded = (size) =>{
   setWidth(width + size)
}
```

Use ref to get image's width like you already did and pass it to the callback function .